# sql data type conversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to use the return value of multiple variables in an insert statement to no avail. any help would be greatly appreciated...

```
--declare vars
DECLARE @strSpiff as VARCHAR(50), @strResult as VARCHAR(50), @strCMD as VARCHAR(100), @strInsert as VARCHAR(500)

--set value for first var. returns text similar to "TOY"
SELECT @strSpiff = strDescription FROM tblNames WHERE username='name'

--get return val of select query and add some text to it. i.e. "TOY_PO"
SET @strResult = @strSpiff+'_PO'

--another query using modified var. This query returns 10.00
SET @strCMD = 'SELECT ' + @strResult + ' FROM tblproducts WHERE  product_name=''something'''

--column "Amount" is of data type money
INSERT INTO tblStuff (Name,Amount)
values('name',CAST(@strCMD as money))
```

error received is "Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax."

I've tried many different cast and convert scenarios with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You are casting a *string* "`SELECT TOY_PO FROM tblproducts...`" to money, not the *result* of that execution of the query. Your current code isn't executing it

There is no cleaner way of doing this because you shouldn't rely on dynamic column names like this. Quite simply, SQL isn't designed to work that way

```
...
SET @strCMD = 'SELECT ''name'', ' + @strResult + ' FROM tblproducts WHERE  product_name=''something'''

INSERT INTO tblStuff (Name,Amount)
EXEC (@strCMD)
```

or

```
...
SET @strCMD = '
INSERT INTO tblStuff (Name,Amount)
SELECT ''name'', ' + @strResult + ' FROM tblproducts WHERE  product_name=''something'''

EXEC (@strCMD)
```

Comment: Is there any other way the conversion can be done successfully? The insert statement works if `CAST(@strCMD as money)` is changed to `'10.00'`

Comment: @user825315: of course it works because 10.00 is a number, not a query. No other cleaner way

Comment: how do I get the return value of the query (10.00) into a variable so I could do something like... `set @strInsert = 'insert into tblStuff (Name,Amount) values(''myname'',' + @strCMD + ')'  exec (@strInsert)`

Comment: No, that would be nested dynamic SQL and suffers the same problem. I gave you 2 examples...

Comment: The examples don't work for my scenario. Thanks for you time though. I will find a different way to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

You can do direct select and insert as below.

```
INSERT tblStuff (Name,Amount)
SELECT name, Amt FROM tblproducts WHERE  product_name='something'
```

Comment: 'name' is not in the table, therefore it can't be selected.

Comment: Do you want "SELECT strDescription+'PO' FROM tblNames WHERE username='name'  " i.e. strDescription+'PO' for name in tblStuff table ?

Comment: no, I need to get the numeric value from @strCMD and have that entered into the insert statement, the field that this value goes into is of data type money.

Comment: OK. Not sure if it would fit your scenario but you can create a function that return amount if name is passed. Something like below.

Comment: create function dbo.UY420(
 @a varchar(50)
)
returns money
as
begin
 declare @b money
 set @b = 2.0
 --
 --
 return @b
end

Comment: And then use that function in select & insert as below -       INSERT tblStuff (Name,Amount)
SELECT name, dbo.UY420('Name') FROM tblproducts WHERE  product_name='something'